# +1 incremental value added to database from pageview

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am currently looking to create a sort of "popular products" style page on my website. I have a mySQL database that stores the products and information such as name, price, productpage url, image etc.

I was thinking the best way for me to easily make this work is if i am able to add a new column to this table "Visits" and have an incremental value added each time a user visits the specific product page and adding this to the row of the product in the "visits" column. This way i can then easily display products and sort by descending, having the most visited at the top.

I have had a look around but can't seem to find a way. Can anyone help me out with a way this would work or if there is a better solution for this? Also would there be any constraints using this method as we do get times of large amounts of traffic.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe you can do it with [google analytics](http://www.whereoware.com/blog/identify-top-product-categories-for-top-profit/2012/05/) but obviously you might not want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need PHP script that will send `UPDATE` query when someone visits page.

```
UPDATE `Products` SET `visits`=`visits`+1 WHERE `product_id` = ?
```

Comment: True but that will update their entire database if there is more than one record. If that's what they want that is. Edit: this comment as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43372459/1

Comment: Ofcoure, that's why they should add `WHERE`. I hope they know it. But, made edit in case...

Comment: if you don't delete that comment ^ they know now ;-) Edit: ah, you added that :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this guys! :) I will test it out